# Displaying the corner coordinates of the triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

**Original:**

[image]

**How can I add the coordinates like this?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoint (-3,1){A},
\tkzDefPoint (4,12){B},
\tkzDefPoint (-9,12){C},
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](C)
\draw[very thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\node[below] at (A) {A(-3,1)};`  Of course, once you read the TikZ manual you will realize the Euclide is largely redundant.

Comment: Only using `tkz-euclide`, you can add a content to your node label: `\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B(4,12)$}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `tkzLabelPoints` for that but use `tkzLabelPoint` instead (individually of course). And add a custom label to your command.

EDIT: added a label to a segment as OP's demand in comments.

[image: tkzLabelPoint and tkzLabelSegment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoint (-3,1){A},
\tkzDefPoint (4,12){B},
\tkzDefPoint (-9,12){C},
\tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$A(-3,1)$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B(4,12)$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](C){$C(-9,12)$}
\draw[very thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelSegment(C,B){$[CB]$}
\end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

In order to add a marking on a segment, and if you want to customize its size, you can add `\tkzMarkSegment[mark=s||,size=10](C,B)` for example, that leads to the following:

[image: tkzMarkSegment]

Comment: thanks @SebGlav, How can I add a marker to the [CB] segment?

Comment: The same way with `tkzLabelSegment`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I may have understand your question the wrong way, please be more specific about what *marker* you want. Maybe this could be another question.

Comment: mark=|| @SebGlav

Comment: Then use `\tkzMarkSegment[mark=||](C,B)`.

Comment: and finally, can we adjust the size of the mark segment? @SebGlav

Comment: See my edit for the size of markings.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6, -1)(3,6)
\psset{unit = 4mm, PointSymbol=none, linecolor=IndianRed, linejoin=1,}
\pstTriangle[PointNameA=\hskip3em A\:{(-3,1)}, PointNameB=\qquad B\:{(4,12)}, PointNameC=C\:{(-9,12)\hskip 3em},%
PosAngle={-90,0,180}](-3,1){A}(4,12){B}(-9,12){C}
\pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=pstslash]{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]